# Use Gstreamer with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gstreamer

I trying to use Gstreamer in Visual Studio 2012. So I installed gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.5.2.msi and gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.5.2.msi, then I added gstreamer-1.0.props in Property Sheet and changed working directory in "properties->configuration properties->debugging" to MY\GSTREAMER\PATH\bin. And tried to compile this:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <gst/gst.h>

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
  GstElement *pipeline; 
  GstBus *bus; 
  GstMessage *msg; 

  /* Initialize GStreamer */ 
  gst_init (&argc, &argv); 
    return 0; 
}
```

But got this issue:

**The procedure entry point g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a could not be located in the dynamic link library libgobject-2.0-0.dll.**

How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution: my program used not right dll, that was the same named dll of GTK#, after deleting GTK#(wrong, but quick ;)) my program started to load the right dll from Gstreamer.